# CorePlot: Updating X Axis range in real time plotting

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, core-plot

I've check out most of the questions that seemed the most relevant but none of them really touched on what I'm having a bit of trouble with at the moment. My problem is that, while I know that I need to update plotSpace.xRange no matter how I try to update it, either nothing happens, or I get a crash.

What I'm currently doing is I have 2 global variables(xMinVal, xMaxVal) declared in my RealTimeScatterPlot.m file, and those are what I'm using for my plotSpace.xRange calculation upon plot initialization. Then, my viewcontroller that is hosting the plot view contains a function that generates and plots a random point every second. Inside this function I track to see if I have more than 25(my default x axis range is from 0 to 50 for the moment) points, and if I do, I attempt to increment my global values in RealTimeScatterPlot.m by one, which should in theory shift the view of my graph by 1. The first incrementation happens, though the view does not shift, nor am I then able to increment again as the values just remain the same. If seeing code would help let me know and I'll edit it in, but its all very straightforward/generic. I'm thinking that instead of a coding issue this is probably just not the way I'm supposed to be implementing this.

Any insight would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do what you want easy like tableview data updating.
here is some part of code what i have done you can use it for reference. Hope this may help you.

```
-(void) fetchArrayOffeedback {

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Pulse"
                                              inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predictate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"sessionKey == %@", appDelegateiPhone.strSessionId];

    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predictate];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
    [sort release];

    NSError *error;

    chartData = (NSMutableArray*)[appDelegate.managedObjectContext
                                            executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    [chartData retain];
    NSLog(@"array count :%d", [chartData count]);

    [graph reloadData];

    CPXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(fiveHour*3)];   
}

- (void)constructScatterPlotForFeedback
{
    [graph release];

    graph = [[CPXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    graph.delegate = self;
    CPTheme *theme = [CPTheme themeNamed:kCPPlainWhiteTheme];
    [graph applyTheme:theme];
    feedbackChart.hostedGraph = graph;
    [feedbackChart setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    graph.paddingLeft = 0.0;
    graph.paddingTop = 0.0;
    graph.paddingRight = 0.0;
    graph.paddingBottom = 0.0;

    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft = 5.0;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop = 10.0;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight = 10.0;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 10.0;

    NSTimeInterval oneHour =  60 * 60;

    CPXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
    plotSpace.delegate = self;

    float xRange;
    xRange = [chartData count] + 1.0;

    if (xRange>5) {
        xRange = 5.0;
    }
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(fiveHour*3)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(-20.0) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(40.0)];


    CPLineStyle *gridline = [CPLineStyle lineStyle];
    gridline.lineColor = [CPColor grayColor];
    gridline.lineWidth = 1.0f;  

    CPXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
    CPXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.majorIntervalLength = CPDecimalFromFloat(fiveHour);
    x.minorTicksPerInterval = 0;
    x.labelOffset=0;

    NSDate *refDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm:ss";

    CPTimeFormatter *timeFormatter = [[[CPTimeFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormatter:dateFormatter] autorelease];
    timeFormatter.referenceDate = refDate;
    x.labelFormatter = timeFormatter;

    CPXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;

    y.minorTicksPerInterval = 0;
    y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPDecimalFromString(@"0.0");
    y.majorIntervalLength = CPDecimalFromString(@"5");
    y.majorGridLineStyle = nil;

    y.visibleRange = [CPPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPDecimalFromFloat(-20.0f) length:CPDecimalFromFloat(40.0f)];
    CPConstraints yConstraints = {CPConstraintNone, CPConstraintFixed};
    y.isFloatingAxis=YES;
    y.constraints=yConstraints;

    CPScatterPlot *dataSourceLinePlot = [[[CPScatterPlot alloc] init] autorelease];
    dataSourceLinePlot.identifier = @"FeedBack Plot";
    dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle.lineWidth = 3.f;
    dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle.lineColor = [CPColor blackColor];
    dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle.dashPattern = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f], nil];
    dataSourceLinePlot.dataSource = self;

    dataSourceLinePlot.opacity = 0.0f;
    dataSourceLinePlot.cachePrecision = CPPlotCachePrecisionDecimal;

    CABasicAnimation *fadeInAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    fadeInAnimation.duration = 1.0f;
    fadeInAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    fadeInAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    fadeInAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    [dataSourceLinePlot addAnimation:fadeInAnimation forKey:@"animateOpacity"];

    CPColor *areaColor1 = [CPColor colorWithComponentRed:0.3 green:0.3 blue:1.0 alpha:0.8];
    CPGradient *areaGradient1 = [CPGradient gradientWithBeginningColor:areaColor1 endingColor:[CPColor clearColor]];
    areaGradient1.angle = -90.0f;

    NSUInteger i;

    [graph addPlot:dataSourceLinePlot];

    NSMutableArray *contentArray1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:100];

    NSMutableArray *customTickLocations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *xAxisLabels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for ( i = 0; i < [chartData count]; i++ ) {
    //for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {  
        [customTickLocations addObject:[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:i]];
        [xAxisLabels addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.1f", 5.0 * i]];
        Pulse *objPulse1 = (Pulse *)[chartData objectAtIndex:i];
//      id x = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:i*fiveHour];
        id x = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:i];
        id y = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[objPulse1.feedBack floatValue]];
        NSLog(@"point of gragh for Performance x:%@, y : %@ ", x, y);
        [contentArray1 addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:x, @"x", y, @"y", nil]];
    }

    NSLog(@"Axis lable count : %d", [xAxisLabels count]);
    NSMutableArray *customLabels = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[chartData count]];
    NSUInteger labelLocation = 0;

    for (NSNumber *tickLocation in customTickLocations) {
        NSLog(@">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> tick location");
        CPAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPAxisLabel alloc] initWithText: [xAxisLabels objectAtIndex:labelLocation++] textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
        newLabel.tickLocation = [tickLocation decimalValue];
        newLabel.offset = x.labelOffset + x.majorTickLength - 5.0f;
        newLabel.rotation = 0;
        [customLabels addObject:newLabel];
        [newLabel release];
    }

    x.axisLabels =  [NSSet setWithArray:customLabels];

    arrScatter = contentArray1;
    [arrScatter retain];
}

-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot 
{

    if ( [(NSString *)plot.identifier isEqualToString:@"FeedBack Plot"] ) {
        return [chartData count];
    }

    return 0;
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    switch ( fieldEnum ) {
        case CPScatterPlotFieldX:
            return (NSDecimalNumber *)[NSDecimalNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:index*fiveHour];
        case CPScatterPlotFieldY:
        {
            Pulse *objPulse1 = (Pulse *)[chartData objectAtIndex:index];
            return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[objPulse1.feedBack floatValue]];          
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

-(CGPoint)plotSpace:(CPPlotSpace *)space willDisplaceBy:(CGPoint)displacement {

    return CGPointMake(displacement.x, 0);
}


/*
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index 
{
    NSDecimalNumber *num = nil;

    if ( [(NSString *)plot.identifier isEqualToString:@"FeedBack Plot"] ) {
        if ( [arrScatter count] != 0) {
            num = [[arrScatter objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:(fieldEnum == CPScatterPlotFieldX ? @"x" : @"y")];
        }
    }
    return num;
 }
*/

-(CPLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

        Pulse *objPulse1 = (Pulse *)[chartData objectAtIndex:index];
        float value = [objPulse1.feedBack floatValue];       
        //CPTextLayer *textLayer = [[CPTextLayer alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", value]];

        CPTextStyle *textStyle = [CPTextStyle textStyle];
        textStyle.color = [CPColor blackColor];

        CPTextLayer *textLayer = [[CPTextLayer alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.1f", value] style:textStyle];
        return textLayer;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what my solution ended up looking like, but seems like a fairly complete answer.

Comment: @KarolyS can you add your own answer with a solution , I am running in exact same troubles .

Comment: @Roma-MT I can see if I can dig up my solution for you in the next day or so, unfortunately it was long enough ago I don't quite remember my solution off the top of my head.

Comment: @Roma-MT Excellent, I'm glad to hear it. If you wouldn't mind posting your solution, or your thought process, someone might be very appreciative later on! Especially since this is pushing 2 years old now.

Comment: @Yes I just thought about... just will adjust it a bit (and add some comments ) :)

Answer (score 1):

I subclassed the real plot graph like this:

NOTE: I didn't put some methods I am using here to draw labels and decide cool of the graph 
I put the present code to show the idea for creating the real time plot .

in my.h

```
#import <CorePlot/CorePlot.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "sharedPrefferences.h"
#import "RMBlurredView.h"//Not really needed I am just using it for my custom label
@interface GenericCPTGraphView : NSView <CPTPlotDataSource,CPTPlotSpaceDelegate>
{

    CPTGraphHostingView *hostView;
    CPTXYGraph *graph;
    NSMutableArray *plotData;
    NSTextField* percentLabel;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle;
    CPTScatterPlot *dataSourceLinePlot;
    NSInteger currentIndex;
    NSTimer* dataTimer;
    BOOL animated;
}

-(void)updateGraph :(NSNumber*)Load;//method that will add the new Dots to the plot.
@end
```

in my.m

```
#define SECTION_COUNT 15 //maybe will be changed to 16 who knows.

static const double kAlpha     = 0.25; // smoothing constant

static const NSUInteger kMaxDataPoints = 40;
static NSString *const kPlotIdentifier = @"Data Source Plot";
@implementation GenericCPTGraphView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        plotData  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:kMaxDataPoints];
        [self generateData];//create plot method
        [self checkGraph];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)checkGraph
{
    currentIndex=0;
    NSDate *refDate       = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:@"12:00 Oct 29, 2009"];
    NSTimeInterval oneDay = 1;
    // Create graph from theme
    graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    CPTTheme *theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTSlateTheme];
    [graph applyTheme:theme];
    graph.paddingLeft = 1.0;
    graph.paddingTop = 1.0;
    graph.paddingRight = 1.0;
    graph.paddingBottom = 1.0;
    graph.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor clearColor]];
    graph.plotAreaFrame.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[self getCPTColorObjectFromHexString:@"062118" alpha:1.0]];
    graph.plotAreaFrame.borderLineStyle = nil;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.cornerRadius = 0;
    hostView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.frame.size.width,self.frame.size.height)];
    hostView.hostedGraph = graph;
    RMBlurredView *LabelView = [[RMBlurredView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1,0+hostView.frame.size.height-16 , hostView.frame.size.width-2, 15)];
    [LabelView setTintColor:[sharedPrefferences colorWithHexColorString:@"000000" alpha:0.5]];
    NSTextField* textLabel = [[NSTextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 1,     LabelView.frame.size.width, 15)];
    dataSourceLinePlot.identifier     = (__bridge id<NSCopying,NSCoding,NSObject>)(kMDItemIdentifier);
    [textLabel setTextColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];
     //    textLabel
    [textLabel setBezeled:NO];
    [textLabel setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [textLabel setEditable:NO];
    [textLabel setSelectable:NO];
    [textLabel setStringValue:@"LOAD"];
    [textLabel sizeToFit];
    percentLabel = [[NSTextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 1, LabelView.frame.size.width, 15)];
    [percentLabel setTextColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];
    [percentLabel setBezeled:NO];
    [percentLabel setDrawsBackground:NO];
    [percentLabel setEditable:NO];
    [percentLabel setSelectable:NO];
   // [percentLabel setStringValue:@"X%"];
    //[percentLabel sizeToFitWithAlignmentRight];
    LabelView.blurRadius = 0;
    dataSourceLinePlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    dataSourceLinePlot.dataSource = self;
    [graph addPlot:dataSourceLinePlot];
    // Setup scatter plot space
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = NO;
    plotSpace.delegate = self;
    CABasicAnimation *fadeInAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    fadeInAnimation.duration = 1.0f;
    fadeInAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    fadeInAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    fadeInAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    [dataSourceLinePlot addAnimation:fadeInAnimation forKey:@"animateOpacity"]; 
    [graph addPlot:dataSourceLinePlot];
    NSTimeInterval xLow       = 0.0;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(xLow) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(oneDay * 40.0)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(100.0)];
    // Axes
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
    CPTXYAxis *x          = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.hidden = YES;
    x.majorIntervalLength         = CPTDecimalFromFloat(oneDay);
    x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0);
    x.minorTicksPerInterval       = 0;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = kCFDateFormatterShortStyle;
    CPTTimeFormatter *timeFormatter = [[CPTTimeFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormatter:dateFormatter];
    timeFormatter.referenceDate = refDate;
    x.labelFormatter            = timeFormatter;
    CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.hidden = YES;
    y.majorIntervalLength         = CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.5);
    y.minorTicksPerInterval       = 1;
    y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromFloat(oneDay);
    // Create a plot that uses the data source method
    //CPTScatterPlot *dataSourceLinePlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    y.minorTicksPerInterval = 0;
    [LabelView addSubview:percentLabel];
    [LabelView addSubview:textLabel];
    [graph.hostingView addSubview:LabelView];
    [self addSubview:hostView];
}

-(void)updateGraph :(NSNumber*)Load
{    
    if ( dataSourceLinePlot ) {
        if ( plotData.count >= 40 ) {
            [plotData removeObjectAtIndex:0];
            [dataSourceLinePlot deleteDataInIndexRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
        }
        CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
        plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(0) length:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(kMaxDataPoints - 2)];
        plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(0) length:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(1)];
        NSUInteger location       = (currentIndex >= kMaxDataPoints ? currentIndex - kMaxDataPoints + 2 : 0);
        CPTPlotRange *newRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(location)
                                                          length:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(kMaxDataPoints - 2)];
    plotSpace.xRange = newRange;
    currentIndex++;
    [plotData addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:((Load.doubleValue - kAlpha) / 100.0)]];
    [percentLabel setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld%%",(Load.integerValue) ]];
    graph.borderWidth = 0.0 ;
    dataSourceLinePlot.borderWidth = 0.0;
    [dataSourceLinePlot setBorderWidth:0.0];
    dataSourceLinePlot.identifier = @"Date Plot";
    lineStyle = [dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    lineStyle.lineWidth              = 2.0;
    [percentLabel sizeToFitWithAlignmentRight];
    lineStyle.lineColor = [self decideColor: [self numberOfSectionsToHighlight:Load.doubleValue]];
    dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;
    [dataSourceLinePlot insertDataAtIndex:(plotData.count - 1) numberOfRecords:1];//inserting object to the plot. 
}
```

}

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Plot Data Source Methods

-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
{
    NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)plotData.count);
    return plotData.count;
}
 -(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    NSNumber *num = nil;

    switch ( fieldEnum ) {
        case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:
            num = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:index + currentIndex - plotData.count];
            break;

        case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:
            num = [plotData objectAtIndex:index];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

return num;
}
@end
```